# XML Traversal: find a specific child node

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <prj:Flow xmlns:prj="url1" xmlns:com="url2" xmlns:ns2="url3" xmlns:con="url4" xmlns:ns0="url5" xmlns:ns1="url6" xmlns:ns3="url7">
    <prj:layout comp="abcd">
      <prj:prop>
         <prj:property name="Hardik" value="5000"/>
         <prj:bond att="1"> New Value/hello/mode </prj:bond>
      </prj:prop>
      <prj:bond att="1"> New Value </prj:bond>
    </prj:layout>
    <prj:layout comp="efgh">
      <prj:prop>
         <prj:property name="Vipul" value="6000"/>
         <prj:bond att="2"> New Value/bye/code </prj:bond>
      </prj:prop>
      <prj:bond att="2"> New Value </prj:bond>
    </prj:layout>
    </prj:Flow>
```

Here each `<layout>` tag has two children - `<prop> and <bond>`. My requirement is to get only the `<bond>` data(attribute and text) from the layout tag and not the one present under the `<prop>` tag. How do I achieve this using jquery only? Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression to return all `<prj:bond>` elements that is direct child of `<prj:layout>` :

```
var result = yourXml.find("prj\\:layout").children("prj\\:bond");
```

Quick demo :

```js
var raw = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<prj:Flow xmlns:prj='url1' xmlns:com='url2' xmlns:ns2='url3' xmlns:con='url4' xmlns:ns0='url5' xmlns:ns1='url6' xmlns:ns3='url7'>
    <prj:layout comp='abcd'>
        <prj:prop>
            <prj:property name='Hardik' value='5000' />
            <prj:bond att='1'> New Value/hello/mode </prj:bond>
        </prj:prop>
        <prj:bond att='1'> New Value </prj:bond>
    </prj:layout>
    <prj:layout comp='efgh'>
        <prj:prop>
            <prj:property name='Vipul' value='6000' />
            <prj:bond att='2'> New Value/bye/code </prj:bond>
        </prj:prop>
        <prj:bond att='2'> New Value </prj:bond>
    </prj:layout>
</prj:Flow>`;
var xml = $($.parseXML(raw));
var result = xml.find("prj\\:layout").children("prj\\:bond").each(function(){
 $("#result").append($(this).text()).append("<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: This does not seem to fetch anything. Its neither throwing an error nor showing any data.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a fiddle, like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/s44hno9n/), to show how you tried to implement the suggested selector and demonstrates how it failed to output the expected result